# How to efficiently solve forward or backword slash issue at the end of a path

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that takes path location from a user and creates some file or directory under that path.

But a user can provide path information with any many ways. like

1. /tmp
2. /tmp/
3. C:\Users\
4. C:\Users

I am creating the new files in the file or directory in the following way

```
data_file = path + "data_file" 
fh = open(data_file, "w")
```

But the absence of forward slash or backword slash sometimes creates a problem.So how can I able to handle that problem efficiently in python.

Comment: Any reasons for down voting? Let OP knows.

Comment: Please tell me reasons for down voting??

Comment: Instead of handling forward or backward slash, you can check whether the given path exist or not before creating file.

Comment: Thanks @DineshPundkar for your reply. Before checking the existence of the file or directory, I needed to make sure the path is correct or not.

Comment: Yes Arijit. Let assume user wants to type '/tmp' but he has entered only 'tmp'. In this case, checking path existence before will help. Once path you know input path is valid, then you can use answer by Kallz.

Comment: @DineshPundkar - Thanks, boss. I got your point.

Answer (score 4):

Use **OS** module for add paths

```
 os.path.join(path1,path2)
```

This module takes care of operating systems like some operating system use the forward slash or some use backward slash.

In your code

```
import os
data_file = os.path.join(path , "data_file") 
fh = open(data_file, "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `os` module so that you don't have to worry about whether the user is using windows or linux.

```
import os
path = '/tmp/' # or '/tmp/' or 'C:\Users\' or 'C:\Users'
dir = os.path.dir(path)  # Won't have trouble with windows/linux or trailing slash 
data_file = os.path.join(dir, 'file.txt')
fh = open(data_file, 'w')
```

Comment: I am getting an error while running the program. Error is __module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'dir'__